# How to get List View Item onTouch method?

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop

I have a ListView and I want to perform Drag and Drop on list items. I am Overridding a `onTouch` method which has two parameters

`@Override public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {}`

In view I am getting complete ListView. How can i get perticular TextView on which key is pressed?

I am able to drag items when if I long press and get that view but i dont want to perform long press action.

Any way to get selected item position in `onTouch`?

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909311/android-list-view-drag-and-drop-sort).

Comment: @Flo.. Its a bit complicated code. :(

Comment: Hey i also face same problem can any one known how to get the Position of List Item when we implement setOnTouchListener for ListView in ListActivity.

Comment: I guess you can find your answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384131/get-item-from-listview-only-with-ontouchlistener

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to implement a custom `Adapter` which you use to populate your `ListView`. In the `getView` method of your `Adapter` you can call `setOnClickListener` on the view that you create, and add an item click listener that way.

There is some sample code of this in [setOnClickListener of a ListView not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402255/setonclicklistener-of-a-listview-not-working).

Comment: I think for drag'n'drop it would be better to implement an OnTouchListener instead of an OnClickListener.

Comment: @Flo good point! I missed that it was for dran and drop rather than simple click handling when ansering. @Harshad there is some useful refrence code for drag and drop in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909311/android-list-view-drag-and-drop-sort

Comment: My app has a ViewFlipper (that implements OnGestureListener) assigned to a ListView item and I noticed that the OnGestureListener was preventing the Adapter's OnItemClickListener from triggering onItemClick(). The solution was to assign a `setOnClickListener` to that specific item in the ListView. Now the custom compound view still triggers `onSingleTapUp` followed by the OnClickListener's `onClick()`

Answer (score 3):

I have added item position in `llItem` tag
in Adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ...
   llItem = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lItem);
   llItem.setTag("" + position);
   llItem.setOnTouchListener(itemTouch);
   ...
}
```

and the extracted item position from tag

```
 OnTouchListener itemTouch = new OnTouchListener() {
    private int position;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.lItem);
       String itemTag = ll.getTag().toString();
       int itemPosition = Integer.parseInt(itemTag);
       ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: By doing this the list selector is disabled !