# OnItemClickListener not triggering on custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, adapter, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

I'm having a problem with OnItemClickListener on a ListView, the OnItemClick overridden method is not triggered... Here's my code:

```
public void popupCatCategories(){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
    View popupCatCategoriesView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_cats_categories, null);  
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupCatCategoriesView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Button btnDismiss = (Button) popupCatCategoriesView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);

    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });

    // listview to display image and text
    ListView listCatCategories = (ListView) popupCatCategoriesView.findViewById(R.id.listCatCategories);

    List<HashMap<String, String>> listCategories = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    db.open();
    Cursor catCategories = db.getAllCatCategoryList();
    if (catCategories.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {                
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hm.put("catCategoryThumbnail", Integer.toString(catCategories.getInt(1)));
            hm.put("catName", catCategories.getString(0));
            listCategories.add(hm);
        } while (catCategories.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();

    listCatCategories.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listCategories));

    Log.i("got it?", "wait for it...");
    listCatCategories.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("got it?", "yea, got it!");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "got it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnCats, 50, -330);
}
```

I'm simply adding some values in an ArrayList of HashMap, each HashMap contains 2 String variables, which are displayed in each row of the ListView. There is only an ImageView and a TextView inside a RelativeLayout for the custom xml layout of the ListView. It displayed fine, except that then I click on a row, nothing happens, it does not trigger the Log or anything. The Overridden method onItemClick is not triggered at all.

I've already tried to setClickable(true) or setItemsCanFocus(false) on the ListView, or setFocusable(false) and setFocusableInTouchMode(false) on the ImageView and TextView (even though its applicable for Checkboxes and Buttons right?).

Here's the custom xml for the ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/catCategoryThumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCatCategoryName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Anyway, I don't know what to do anymore, can anyone please help me?

If you need anymore information, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: have you tried this:      listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

Comment: I just tried, still nothing...

Comment: have you done textView.setFocusable(flase) dynamically in the code? Try it because some days ago it din't work for me (just giving it in xml file). It worked only when I did this by coding dynamically.

Comment: Yes I did try that, it still didn't work :-/ I think I tried all possible solutions given on the other questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an alternate solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6579192/1759005. It's working just as fine.

Comment: That's the way I'm implementing my lists, but I didn't want to suggest such extensive rewrite ;)

Comment: I prefer this way than losing another day for nothing lol I'm done anyway, so :)

Comment: @Saran did you implement yours such that you still get the clicked effect when selecting a row?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have extended the ArrayAdapter and had to handle the onTouch events for the row (and the text on the row). For MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN/MOVE I just changed the background, for MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL I changed the background back to default and for the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP I did the actual action. Of course, if you want actions for long-press, you have to implement the onItemLongClickedCallback, too.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your view isn't accepting the event is because the TextView (which is focusable) is overriding it and taking all touch/click action for itself.

You just have to set these for the TextView:

`android:focusable="false"`

`android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`

Comment: I've already tried that, it's still not working. onItemClick is still not triggering :(