# Fragments with listview cannot swipe left right

Tags: android, listview, view, fragment

I have 3 fragments, each one with a listview.
The problem is that the ListView intercepts the touch events and I can no longer swipe left or right inside the lists.

I leave the code from one of the fragments:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.unlp.talk_louder.activities.CategoryActivityFragment">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/nombre_categoria"
        android:id="@+id/catName"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_newCategory"
        android:id="@+id/inputCategoryName" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/category_phrases"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addPhraseBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/new_phrase_btn"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:id="@+id/phrasesListview"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddCategory"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add_cat"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cancel_cat"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579009/how-to-get-list-view-item-ontouch-method

Comment: You can use recyclerview since it has ItemTouchHelper class for swiping items left and right

Comment: @FaisalNaseer, do you think that I should implement an adaptar to populate the listview? is that what are you suggesting?

Comment: @NancyY it's interesting your solution to my problem, I thougt that it was simple changing the tag to recycleView, but i need to do some changes more. I will try

Comment: unfortunately its not like so you will have to override the touchEvents.