# nothing happens when an list item is clicked

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-fragments

I am new in android. When I click on listview item then nothing happens. I checked my code 3 times but couldn't get the what is the problem. I want when an item is clicked the user name will show in a text view in next activity. I don't know what is the problem.

Here is my listview item code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="1dp">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/row_postPic"
        android:background="#dcdcdc"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/url"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_date"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="name"
        android:id="@+id/row_name"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/row_userid"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/row_date"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/row_date"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/row_userid"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/row_userid" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="date"
        android:id="@+id/row_date"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageToDownload2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/row_tittle"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/row_tittle"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="tittle"
        android:id="@+id/row_tittle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_postPic"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Category"
        android:id="@+id/row_cat"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/row_postPic"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/row_name"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/row_name" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="UserId"
        android:id="@+id/row_userid"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageToDownload2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageToDownload2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageToDownload2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="PostId"
        android:id="@+id/row_postid"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Like"
        android:id="@+id/row_like"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_tittle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is list adapter

```
public class PostAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Post> listData;

    public PostAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Post> listData){
        this.context = context;
        this.listData = listData;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    class ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvlike,tvTittle,tvPostId,tvUseId,tvName,tvCat,tvDate;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if(view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_item,null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvTittle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_tittle);
            viewHolder.tvPostId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_postid);
            viewHolder.tvUseId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_userid);
            viewHolder.tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_name);
            viewHolder.tvCat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_cat);
            viewHolder.tvlike = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_like);
            viewHolder.tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_date);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        Post post = listData.get(position);
        String rpostid = post.getPost_id();
        String ruserid = post.getUser_id();
        String rname = post.getUser_name();
        String rcat = post.getPost_cat();
        String rlike = post.getLikes();
        String rdate = post.getPost_time();
        String rtittle = post.getPost_title();
        viewHolder.tvPostId.setText(rpostid);
        viewHolder.tvUseId.setText(ruserid);
        viewHolder.tvName.setText(rname);
        viewHolder.tvCat.setText("Category "+rcat);
        viewHolder.tvlike.setText("Toatal Likes "+rlike);
        viewHolder.tvDate.setText(rdate);
        viewHolder.tvTittle.setText(rtittle);

        return view;
    }
}
```

here is the home activity

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

    ListView listView;
    PostAdapter adapter;
    TextView userId;
    ArrayList<Post> postArrayList;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    DBHandler handler;
    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_post, container, false);
        listView = (ListView)  view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
            new DataFetcherTask().execute();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Internet Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item clicked : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                userId = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.row_userid);
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PostView.class);
                i.putExtra("userid", userId.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        return view;

    }

    private class DataFetcherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
            String serverData = null;// String object to store fetched data from server
            // Http Request Code start
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://xyz.lt/json.php");
            try {
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                serverData = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                Log.d("response", serverData);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Http Request Code end
            // Json Parsing Code Start
            try {
                postArrayList = new ArrayList<Post>();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(serverData);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("post");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObjectPOST = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String post_id = jsonObjectPOST.getString("post_id");
                    String user_id = jsonObjectPOST.getString("user_id");
                    String user_name = jsonObjectPOST.getString("user_name");
                    String post_title = jsonObjectPOST.getString("post_title");
                    String likes = jsonObjectPOST.getString("likes");
                    String post_cat = jsonObjectPOST.getString("post_cat");
                    String post_time = jsonObjectPOST.getString("post_time");
                    Post post = new Post();
                    post.setPost_id(post_id);
                    post.setUser_id(user_id);
                    post.setUser_name(user_name);
                    post.setPost_title(post_title);
                    post.setLikes(likes);
                    post.setPost_cat(post_cat);
                    post.setPost_time(post_time);
                    handler.addPost(post);// Inserting into DB
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            //Json Parsing code end
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            ArrayList<Post> postList = handler.getAllPost();
            adapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), postList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        new DataFetcherTask().execute();
        ArrayList<Post> postList = handler.getAllPost();
        adapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), postList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        handler = new DBHandler(getActivity());
        new DataFetcherTask().execute();
    }
}
```

I want when item will click then new activity will open here is the new activity

```
public class PostView extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_view);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent!=null) {
            String stringData= intent.getStringExtra("userid");
            textView.setText(stringData);
        }
    }
}
```

In this project when some click on the listview item then it pass the vaue of textview of the user name to new intent but as list item clicklistner is not working so I am unable to do that.

**Answer is : Do not use Scroll View in Listview Custom item.**

Comment: why you have added `setOnClickListener ` to `view ` ?

Comment: Your  userId = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.row_userid); is empty when you click onItemClick Listener. Try out below line
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PostView.class);
            i.putExtra("userid", postArrayList.get(position));

Comment: i saw that on internet when i was finding the solution of this problem click and forgot to remove that

Comment: it is giving an exception red underline

Comment: @HoneyKamboj I have edit my answer. Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PostView.class); i.putExtra("userid", postArrayList.get(position).getUser_id());

Comment: @AKSiddique thanks for help but i need one more help when i clicked list item then it does not open new intent its just showing A Toast "You Clicked"

Comment: @HoneyKamboj AppCompatActivity uses the SupportFragmentManager, you need to switch to SupportFragment and SupportFragmentManager

Comment: i could't understand ??

Comment: you can refer this answer for the listview item: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47549583/7445389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might sound unrelevant, but will u try your code by removing the `ScrollView` from the `list item layout`? because the click event is taken by the scrollView and hence there seems to be problem with your `onItemCLickListener`

Comment: Thanks its working now, means problem is  Scroll view therefore my code was not worked, Thanks again.  :)

Comment: thanks for help but i need one more help when i clicked list item then it does not open new intent its just showing A Toast "You Clicked"

Comment: there should be problem with context, try `getContext()` or `getApplicationContexr()` or `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` etc

Comment: '@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item clicked : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                userid= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.row_userid);
                Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), PostView.class);
                i.putExtra("user_id", postArrayList.get(position).getUser_id());
                startActivity(i);

            }'      what change i need in this code

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Comment: that problem is solved but app crash when i click on list item  it is giving null pointer exception on **i.putExtra("user_id", postArrayList.get(position).getUser_id());**

Answer (score 0):

As I Know you already apply onItemClick on your listview thats why it is not working. both onitemclick and onClick doesn't work together better option use onClick in place of onItemClick.

Another thing this is not to good do other thing in onCreateView as it is only for View Inflate. Remove this lines of code from onCreateView to onActivityCreated

```
 listView = (ListView)  view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
            new DataFetcherTask().execute();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Internet Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item clicked : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                userId = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.row_userid);
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PostView.class);
                i.putExtra("userid", userId.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: in your getview method

Comment: Sorry, that was written by mistake but that was not in the original code

Comment: its ok... not an issue

Comment: thanks for help but i need one more help when i clicked list item then it does not open new intent its just showing A Toast "You Clicked"

Comment: where you use You clicked toast ?

Comment: that problem is done but there is a new problem app close when i clicked list item

Comment: listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), PostView.class);
                i.putExtra("post_id", postArrayList.get(position).getPost_id());
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

Comment: null pointer exception on **i.putExtra("user_id", postArrayList.get(position).getUser_id());**

Comment: print the value of postArrayList.get(position).getPost_id()); startActivity(i);

Comment: and also check the value of getACtivity

Comment: not working i used log to print but it give exception about nullpointer and close the app

Comment: system.out.println(postArrayList.get(position).getPost_id()).tostring());

Comment: actually i didnot pass string and also did't initialized textview in home

Comment: what valve is null ?

Comment: actually i didnot pass string and also did't initialized textview in home

Answer (score 0):

```
try adding 

android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
in your main layout

eg.`
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:paddingBottom="1dp">`

and set OnItemClickListener to your listView
```